# Combining CMake FetchContent and git --single-branch

Tags: git, cmake, external-project, fetchcontent

I have a git repository with various dependencies distributed over separate branches (some of which take a lot of space). In a separate repository I have a CMake project which utilizes **FetchContent** to pull specific dependencies from their corresponding branches.
The default behavior of `git clone` executed by **ExternalProject_Add** (which is called by **FetchContent**) is to fetch **all** existing branches - this means that all dependencies are downloaded even though **FetchContent** is told to only pull a specific branch - this causes a massive overhead due to downloading excessive data.

A direct solution to my issue is to perform `git clone` with `--single-branch` argument which allows to only fetch the target branch. However, due to reasons described [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17770) also visible in [ExternalProject.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake#L1458) **ExternalProject** is explicitly telling git to *not* perform a single-branch clone.

The way I see is there's not many options to workaround this issue:

- Make a separate repository for each dependency

  - I want to avoid this due to numerous dependencies being stored on the repo + for convenience purposes
- Override **FetchContent.cmake** and **ExternalProject.cmake**

  - Is this even a good approach? The only change I would do is replacing `--no-single-branch` with `--single-branch` in **ExternalProject.cmake**
  - How does one even accomplish that? I copied both files to a path specified with `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, but it did not seem to work. Perhaps I did something wrong?
- Giving up on using **FetchContent** completely and creating a custom implementation of dependency pulling for this specific purpose

  - Seems like lots of trouble

Is there any other solution (perhaps much easier and cleaner) to this issue or should I go with one of the above options?

I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

### Problem example

I have a git repository with multiple branches - `A`, `B`, `C`.
Let's assume that branch `B` contains very heavy data (e.g. 1GB) whereas most other branches are lightweight.

In a separate repository with a **CMake** project I want to pull specific branches which contain project dependencies. This is done using **FetchContent**:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    A
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:X/Dependency_repository.git
    GIT_TAG        A
    GIT_SHALLOW    TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
  )
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(A)
```

Despite of performing a "shallow" clone, **FetchContent** causes *all* branches to be fetched resulting in a massive overhead. I only want to pull branch `A`, but `B` and `C` are also downloaded which takes up much more cloning time and disk space.

Comment: If you choose to override `ExternalProject.cmake`, `--branch A` is also needed to work with `--single-branch`.

Comment: @ElpieKay True! There's also other issues, e.g. if I switch to a different branch in CMakeLists.txt, the default behavior in which ExternalProject performs a checkout needs to be changed, too. There's probably many more adjustments needed to ensure robustness.